# No clue how to execute idea: Runic Chart (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, graph

So I want to have this chart for a game I'll be hosting soon. The way I want it to work is that when you hover over a specific symbol, or rune, it will have a little dropdown giving information on it, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXqBL.png) I got this to work, but I forgot to have it be a fluid design. And that's quite an issue, considering that most of the future users of this site have very different screen resolutions than me. And I have no clue how to make this idea work with a fluid design. Please help me out?

Here's the code if it helps:

```css
.pyramid {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 150px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 35px;
 }
 
 
 .souldropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 860px;
  top: 50px;
 }

 .soulcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .souldropdown:hover .soulcontent {
  display: block;
 }

 
 .honordropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 749px;
  top: 142px;
 }

 .honorcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .honordropdown:hover .honorcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .faithdropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 638px;
  top: 250px;
 }

 .faithcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .faithdropdown:hover .faithcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .fatedropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 518px;
  top: 348px;
 }

 .fatecontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .fatedropdown:hover .fatecontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .balancedropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 852px;
  top: 395px;
 }

 .balancecontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .balancedropdown:hover .balancecontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .perceptiondropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 558px;
  top: 278px;
 }

 .perceptioncontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .perceptiondropdown:hover .perceptioncontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .intuitiondropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 823px;
  top: 280px;
 }

 .intuitioncontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .intuitiondropdown:hover .intuitioncontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .bodydropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 177px;
  top: 585px;
 }

 .bodycontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .bodydropdown:hover .bodycontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .minddropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 1197px;
  top: 513px;
 }

 .mindcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .minddropdown:hover .mindcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .beautydropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 747px;
  top: 529px;
 }

 .beautycontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .beautydropdown:hover .beautycontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .condropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 553px;
  top: 372px;
 }

 .concontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .condropdown:hover .concontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .unddropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 639px;
  top: 372px;
 }

 .undcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .unddropdown:hover .undcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .thoughtdropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 1041px;
  top: 357px;
 }

 .thoughtcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .thoughtdropdown:hover .thoughtcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .knowledgedropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 1027px;
  top: 406px;
 }

 .knowledgecontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .knowledgedropdown:hover .knowledgecontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .dexdropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 489px;
  top: 353px;
 }

 .dexcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .dexdropdown:hover .dexcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .strdropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 302px;
  top: 410px;
 }

 .strcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .strdropdown:hover .strcontent {
  display: block;
 }
 
 
 .desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 
 .h {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #999;
 }
 
 li a {
  display: block;
  color:#e6f0ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 44px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  font-size: 18px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NeoCSS.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 
 <img class="pyramid" src="runes/pyramid.png" alt="Rune Pyramid" width="50%">

 <div class="souldropdown">
   <img src="runes/soul.png" alt="Soul Rune" height="50">
   <div class="soulcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Soul Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   It must be drawn with another rune to be focused.
   <hr>
   Connects to spirituality, spirits, emotion, and feeling (target must be living)
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="honordropdown">
   <img src="runes/honor.png" alt="Honor Rune" width="60">
   <div class="honorcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Honor Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk, and blood.
   <hr>
   Connects to warriors, soldiers, and fallen heroes.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="faithdropdown">
   <img src="runes/faith.png" alt="Faith Rune" width="60">
   <div class="faithcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Faith Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk, and blood.
   <hr>
   Connects to religious peoples, deities, and spirits.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="fatedropdown">
   <img src="runes/fate.png" alt="Fate Rune" width="60">
   <div class="fatecontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Fate Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk, and blood.
   <hr>
   Difficult to harness, but if used correctly, can be used to control fate itself.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="balancedropdown">
   <img src="runes/balance.png" alt="Balance Rune" width="70">
   <div class="balancecontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Balance Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk, and blood.
   <hr>
   Difficult to harness, but if used correctly, can be used to control the balance of anything.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="perceptiondropdown">
   <img src="runes/perception.png" alt="Perception Rune" width="40">
   <div class="perceptioncontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Perception Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   <hr>
   Allows you to affect any one of the five senses of the target.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="intuitiondropdown">
   <img src="runes/intuition.png" alt="Intuition Rune" width="60">
   <div class="intuitioncontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Intuition Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   <hr>
   Allows you to affect the intuition (e.g. scepticism) of the target.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="bodydropdown">
   <img src="runes/body.png" alt="Body Rune" width="55">
   <div class="bodycontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Body Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk and blood.
   It must be drawn with another rune to be focused.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect the physical form of the target (must be living).
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="minddropdown">
   <img src="runes/mind.png" alt="Mind Rune" width="55">
   <div class="mindcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Mind Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk and blood.
   It must be drawn with another rune to be focused.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect the mental form of the target (must be living).
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="beautydropdown">
   <img src="runes/beauty.png" alt="Beauty Rune" width="55">
   <div class="beautycontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Beauty Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk and blood.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect how attractive the target looks to others.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="condropdown">
   <img src="runes/constitution.png" alt="Constitution Rune" width="45">
   <div class="concontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Constitution Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk and blood.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect the health of the target.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="unddropdown">
   <img src="runes/understanding.png" alt="Understanding Rune" width="45">
   <div class="undcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Understanding Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk and blood.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect how well the target can understand any particular subject, which must be specified with other runes.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="thoughtdropdown">
   <img src="runes/thought.png" alt="Thought Rune" width="45">
   <div class="thoughtcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Thought Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect the mental process of the target.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="knowledgedropdown">
   <img src="runes/knowledge.png" alt="Knowledge Rune" width="45">
   <div class="knowledgecontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Knowledge Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect what the target knows and remembers.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="dexdropdown">
   <img src="runes/dexterity.png" alt="Dexterity Rune" width="45">
   <div class="dexcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Dexterity Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk and runic chalk.
   <hr>
   Can be used to physically affect how agile or flexible the target is.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="strdropdown">
   <img src="runes/strength.png" alt="Strength Rune" width="45">
   <div class="strcontent">
  <div class="desc">
   The Strength Rune.<br>
   <hr>
   This rune can be drawn using arcane chalk, runic chalk, and blood.
   <hr>
   Can be used to affect the muscle mass of the target.
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentage instead of px for width, left, top, bottom, right, margins etc. And use css @media rules for different device width: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp